# Message is org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, suitescript2.0

I am receiving the below error when executing my script. The script has been running for about a week now with no issues. After receiving the error, I tried testing in our Sandbox environment and did not encounter the error. The script is exactly the same. When I execute the script in Production, it only processes the first line of information and then throws the error.

Message is org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Throwable (java.lang.String and java.lang.Throwable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (INVOCATION_WRAPPER$sys#81)

Here is the code I am using:

```
     function updateVendorBills(billId, custId) {
        log.debug('Initiate update function.', billId + '/' + custId);
        
        var vendorBill = nsRecord.load({
            type: nsRecord.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
            id: billId,
            isDynamic: false
        });
        
        var lineCount = vendorBill.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
        log.debug('lineCount is: ', lineCount);
        
        for (i = 0; i < lineCount; i++){
             
            vendorBill.setSublistValue({
                sublistId : 'item',
                fieldId   : 'customer',
                line      : i,
                value     : custId
            });
        }
        vendorBill.save();  
    }
    
    function getInputData() {
        var vendorBillSearchObj = nsSearch.load({
            id : 'customsearch3826'
        });

        var searchResultCount = vendorBillSearchObj.runPaged().count;
        log.debug('vendorBillSearchObj result count', searchResultCount);
        return vendorBillSearchObj;
    }
    /**
    * @param {MapReduceContext.map} context
    */
    function map(context) {
        var result = JSON.parse(context.value).values;
        log.debug('result', result);
        var custId = result['entity.appliedToTransaction'].value;
        var billId = result.internalid.value;
        log.debug('billId/custId', billId + '/' + custId);
        context.write({
            key: billId,
            value: custId
        });
        
        updateVendorBills(billId, custId);
    }
```